# reactjs- Axios post returns empty object

Tags: reactjs, axios, json-server

New to Reactjs. I'm trying to post data to a local server using axios, but it is returning an empty object. What am i doing wrong? I need to send a name and an email to the json file.

```
const FormNew = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

  const handleChangeName = (event) => {
    setName(...name, { name: event.target.value });
  };

  const handleChangeEmail = (event) => {
    setEmail(...email, { email: event.target.value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    axios
      .post("http://localhost:3002/posts", {
        name: name,
        email: email,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
      });
  };

  return (
    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Field.Text
        label="Name"
        name="name"
        type="text"
        onChange={handleChangeName}
      />
      <Field.Text
        label="Email"
        name="email"
        type="email"
        onChange={handleChangeEmail}
      />
      <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
    </Form>
  );
};
export default FormNew;
```

Json file where i'm trying to send data.

```
{
  "posts": [
    {
      "name": "JSON SERVER",
      "email": "json@net.com",
      "id": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: We'll need the code on the receiving end of http://localhost:3002/posts/ to be able to tell what's going on here.

Comment: @WillWalsh i added the json file

Comment: I mean the server code at that URL that handles the receipt of the data from the ReactJS frontend. Is it a NodeJS/Express server handling `:3002/posts`? Possibly also try adding a `console.log({name, email});` before the `axios.post` call to ensure that the data is being seen.

Comment: @WillWalsh this? `POST /posts/ 201 33.528 ms - 42`

Comment: add  `console.log(name, email)` when you trigger the `handleSubmit `

Comment: @linchong it returns `{name: "", email: ""}`

Comment: Your `setName` `setEmail` are used in the wrong way, so your `name` `email` is always empty.

Comment: @linchong I replaced the hooks, but they are still returning empty.

Comment: Is it an interface to your local server? `http://localhost:3002/posts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hooks are used in the wrong way, try to use it like this

```
  const handleChangeName = (event) => {
    setName(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleChangeEmail = (event) => {
    setEmail(event.target.value);
  };
```